# Calculating the bounding box for geographic coordinates

Tags: algorithm, google-maps, geometry, geospatial

Given a list of coordinates, how do I calculate the minimum bounding rectangle (MBR), avoiding the global gotchas described in the 
[Unlocking the Mysteries of the Bounding Box](http://www.stonybrook.edu/libmap/coordinates/seriesa/no2/a2.htm)?

Google Maps API method [`fitBounds()`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) seems to be handling the gotchas well.

### Edit:

Using an example from the article above, let's say I have to calculate a bounding box for two locations in the imaginary country of Boxtopia: `point A(170, 40)` and `point B(-170, 50)`. If construct my bounding box using `xmin, ymin` as the southwest corner and `xmax, ymax` as the northwest corner, I'll get `(-170, 40)` and `(170, 50)` respectively, a box which would span 340 degrees instead of minimum 20 degrees.

Comment: The global gotchas are relative to the data you are trying to represent. What data are we talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 1D problem, you are looking for the largest empty interval on a 'circle'. Sorting the data, and then looking for the largest gap will provide the answer in O(N.log(N)).

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution is to sort the x coordinates and incrementally add add 360 to the lowest values and see if it results in a smaller bound.